# How can I share cache with multiple users and roles?

Tags: 8, users, caching

In my custom module, I define a custom block that performs an expensive operation:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
  $data = get_expensive_data();
  $agent_number = get_agent_number_from_context();
  return [
    '#theme' => 'my_custom_module',
    '#cache' => [
      'keys' => ['my_block', 'full_version', $agent_number],
      'tags' => ['my_custom_module'],
      'max-age' => 86400,
    ],
  ];
}
```

The caching works except when another user views the block or a user with a different role view the page; it creates a new cache item. Is it possible to have cache only one time for multiple users/roles?

**Edit**

I tried the following (ended up using `route` context just to not add another variable to my problem):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
  $data = get_expensive_data();
  return [
    '#theme' => 'my_custom_module',
    '#data' => $data,
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => ['route'],
      'tags' => ['my_module'],
      'max-age' => 86400,
    ],
  ];
}
```

Noticed when I had the block using Layout Builder via Page Manager, no item got added to the `cache_render` table (that might be a separate issue).  When I added the block on default Drupal Block Layout I noticed that it still created a new cache record for every user.  For example:

User 1 navigated to: /my-account/A123 and the following record got added to the `cache_render` table:

**cid**

```
entity_view:block:mycustomblock:[languages:language_interface]=en:[route]=entity.node.canonical7ccb4f15749b8c9e759f0016bfc863bd5e6bef88ea0a9dfe7b1cbe2687d30b32:[theme]=my_theme:[url.site]=http://mysite.test:[user]=1
```

**tags**

```
block_view config:block.block.mycustomblock config:user.role.administrator config:user.role.authenticated my_module rendered user:1
```

User 72 navigated to: /my-account/A123 and the following record got added to the `cache_render` table:

**cid**

```
entity_view:block:mycustomblock:[languages:language_interface]=en:[route]=entity.node.canonical7ccb4f15749b8c9e759f0016bfc863bd5e6bef88ea0a9dfe7b1cbe2687d30b32:[theme]=my_theme:[url.site]=http://mysite.test:[user]=79
```

**tags**

```
block_view config:block.block.mycustomblock config:user.role.agent config:user.role.authenticated my_module rendered user:79
```

With using contexts, I am still seeing it create a new record for every user.

**Edit 3**

I think my test form Edit 2 is invalid because I was trying to make the block work outside of page manager but I needed the context from page manager so it was using the logged-in users. Long story short, I need to figure out why context caching isn't working (although key caching is working) when using Page Manager or Layout Manager.

Comment: In case you didn't know, `max-age` doesn't work for anonymous users (anonymous user role). See [Limitations of max-age](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-max-age#s-limitations-of-max-age)

Comment: @NoSssweat I did not know that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching is shared with multiple users or roles by default, unless you add a cache context like `user` or `user.roles`.

Otherwise it's hard to tell what the code in the question wants to achieve.

1. If it wants to set block cache keys, then you can't do it from here
   and you don't need to. They're set automatically.
   `get_agent_number_from_context()` should probably be a custom
   `cache_context.agent_number` which you then could add to the block
   build array to vary the cached block by this variable:

   ```
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function build() {
     $data = get_expensive_data();
     return [
       '#theme' => 'my_custom_module',
       '#data' => $data,
       '#cache' => [
         'contexts' => ['agent_number'],
         'max-age' => 86400,
       ],
     ];
   }
   ```

   How to create a custom cache context:
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts#recognize-discover-create
2. If it wants to cache the expensive data on its own (which
   makes sense if you want to reuse the rendered result in other places
   not necessarily blocks), then you need to execute
   `get_expensive_data()` in a `#pre_render` callback to avoid that it
   gets executed in case of a cache hit. See
   https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-8-performance-render-caching

Edit 1:
The cids you have added to the question contain a cache context for the user. I can't tell by the code shown so far how it ends up in your block. But there is also a cache tag of the user, so there has to be some code retrieving and rendering the current user.

Edit 2:
Assuming the theme is the same there is also a default `user.permissions` cache context for all render caching which probably kicks in now that `user` is removed. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2493033

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense.  I tried to create a custom cache context but wasn't able to view the agent number context. It might be because of page manager.  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293098/unable-to-see-page-builder-context-in-cache-context

Comment: For some reason I am not seeing the cache data get stored when logged in with multiple roles when using `'contexts' => ['agent_number'],`. I even tried `'contexts' => ['user'],`. Is there a special way to enable this to work for authenticated users?

Comment: Also, would these still be added to the `cache_render` table? I am not seeing anything in the `cache_dynamic_page_cache` table but I'm assuming that would be only for full pages and not blocks.

Comment: A block is cached by default, even without an cache metadata like tags or contexts. Blocks become part of pages unless they are placeholdered (but then you see the placeolder instead). If you don't see anything in those cache tables my guess would be that you have disabled caching in your dev environment.

Comment: Actually, when I had the block on the page via Page Manager/Layout Builder the record didn't get added to `cache_render`. Weird that if I used my original method `keys` it did add it.  I added an Edit section to my question of what I tried. You will notice that I am seeing the same issue of a separate cache item get added for each user.

Comment: Yes, when you add a set of cache keys (see the second part of the answer) you are generating your own cache entry, but don't call it `my_block`, because it is not a cached block.

Comment: I think in order for me to figure this out I need to figure out why caching from contexts is not working (although working with keys) in Page Manager/Layout Manager. Would you by any chance have a recommendation where in code to look?

Comment: ... although working with keys ... Yes, if this is working for you then use it. You create your own cacheable render element independent from where it is placed. I couldn't tell from the original question where your code was heading, especially because of the naming of the cache keys. So I presented two possible ways to improve the code, where the second one has nothing to do with block caching anymore.